# Open a StreamConnection on BlackBerry

Tags: xml, sockets, blackberry, java-me

I'm trying to get and parse an XML file.  I am following the sample code in "[How To - Use the XML Parser](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800599/How_To_-_Use_the_XML_Parser.html?nodeid=820554&vernum=0)" but when I put my url in the sample code it just hangs on requesting forever.  If I put the same URL in the html demo I get the text of the xml file.  I do not understand why one works and the other doesn't.  The htmldemo does have some kind of flow control built in, is that why it works?
I am using JDE version 5.0.0.14

```
//providing the location of the XML file,
//your address might be different
conn=(StreamConnection)Connector.open("http://localhost/bbxml/bookstore.xml");
```

Comment: Do you have the MDS simulator running when you try to access your url?

Comment: Yes,I have checked the Launch Mobile Data Connection Service(MDS-CS) with simulator

Comment: You should put all your code that is used to connect, not just one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use localhost on BlackBerry/MDS, open a command-prompt, type hostname and use that instead.

Comment: I even tried with this link http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml still its not working . Whats wrong with the code . Plz help me out its my first blackberry project !